# docker dont generate new image from docker build

Tags: docker, docker-build

I'm in low cost project that we send to container registry (DigitalOcean) only latest image.

But all time, after running:

```
docker build .
```

Is generating the same digest, every time.

This is my script for build:

```
docker build .
docker tag {image}:latest registry.digitalocean.com/{company}/{image}:latest;
docker push registry.digitalocean.com/{company}/{image}
```

I tried:

```
BUILD_VERSION=`date '+%s'`;

docker build -t {image}:"$NOW" -t {image}:latest .
docker tag {image}:latest registry.digitalocean.com/{company}/{image}:latest;
docker push registry.digitalocean.com/{company}/{image}
```

but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Editing my answer, what David said is correct - the push with out the tag should pick up latest tag.

If you provide what you have in your local repository and the output of the above commands, it would shed more light to your problem.

Edit 2:

I think I have figured out on why:

> Is generating the same digest, every time.

This means, although you are running your docker build - there has been no change to the underlying artifacts which are being packaged into the image and hence it results into the same digest.

Comment: `...:latest` is the default tag if you don't specify one; I wouldn't expect adding it to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes layers are cached but there are changes that aren't detected so you can delete the image or use 'docker system prune' to force clearing cache [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)